# UIView.backgroundColor gets updated on the next run only - iphone sdk

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uibackgroundcolor

The implementation is really simple. I'm updating a UIView's background color.

For the selection of color, I'm using an external component.

However, on selection of color, it doesn't get updated instantly. Instead, the background color changes when I run the project again.

Any insights to the issue ? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

The below method is called from viewWillAppear method of my class

```
-(IBAction)changeColor:(id)sender
{      
    NSArray *arrColor = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"color"]]; 
    [self.viewWithSilhouetteImage performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setBackgroundColor:) withObject:[UIColor colorWithHue:[[arrColor objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] saturation:[[arrColor objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] brightness:[[arrColor objectAtIndex:2] floatValue] alpha:1.0] waitUntilDone:NO];
    [btnSelectPhoto setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithHue:[[arrColor objectAtIndex:0] floatValue] saturation:[[arrColor objectAtIndex:1] floatValue] brightness:[[arrColor objectAtIndex:2] floatValue] alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I tried debugging and even logged. The method's getting called every time the color is updated but it isnt reflecting until the next run.

The component I'm using is ESCColorpicker: 
https://github.com/JARinteractive/ESCObservable/tree/master/example/ESCColorPicker

Comment: Would like to see your code. Possibly you have set view's background color on it's launch only.

Comment: Make sure that you are updating the color on the main thread as all UI updates have to happen on that thread.

Comment: You aren't using the external component correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For performance reason NSUserDefaults is not flushed automatically but once in a while.

After you do :

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:aColor forKey:@"color"];
```

you should call

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Comment: Yes, that's already in place. Thanks anyways for your response!